# Postgres: Unique constrain on Column-A, Column-B [value1]

Tags: postgresql, constraints, unique-constraint

I have a table `applications` which has `user_id`, `status` among other field. `status` could be `[0,1,2]`.

I need to impose a constrain that in the applications table, there cannot be multiple rows having the same `user_id` in `0` status. There however could be multiple rows having `user_id` in status `1` or `2`.

To demonstrate, this is not allowed:

```
user_id | status
abc     | 0
abc     | 0
```

But, this is allowed:

```
user_id | status
abc     | 1
abc     | 1
```

How do I impose such a constrain? I'm using Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filtered unique index for that:

```
create unique index on applications (user_id)
where status = 0;
```